# NSURLSession timeout

Tags: ios, json, swift, timeout

I have a function where I make a request to get a `JSON`.

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5

let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
     let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
     onCompletion(json, error)
})
task.resume()
```

This works, but I´m having issues with the timeout. If the request takes more than 5 seconds I want to cancel the operation. Any ideas how to do this?

The call can take more than 5 seconds but it stills fires and the timeout does not do anything. Do I have to do anything if the timeout is fired?

**Update**

```
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

        let urlconfig = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 5
        urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 5
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: urlconfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)
            onCompletion(json, error)
        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: you already are using the time out interval request  for 5 sec. What else do u need ?

Comment: This is not working... I tried to change that value to 0.01 and it still loaded when it took over 4 seconds to load. Do I have to handle if the timeoutIntervalForRequest or timeoutIntervalForResource is fired?

Comment: @Mr.T, it´s not a duplicate I have read that post and check my comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot change the timeout on the `sharedSession` or a sessions `configuration` property. You have to set the timeout when the session is created. See this for an example of how to create a session and its timeout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30427187/78496

Comment: I don´t quite get how to integrate that post with my code, any ideas?

Comment: @user5700760 - Replace your `let session = ...` line with the four lines from that answer (though rather than referring to `self.session`, you could just refer to `session`). The key point is to instantiate your own `NSURLSessionConfiguration`, set its timeout parameters, and then instantiate your own `NSURLSession` using that configuration rather than using the shared session.

Comment: I have now updated my code (see the update in my question), but now when the code reaches the timeout it crashes at `let json:JSON = JSON(data: data!)` with the message: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: If it timed-out then `data` will be nil as it didn't receive any. You have to check if `error` is not nil before you do anything with `data`

Comment: Thanks chedabob and Rob, appreciate your help.