Socket.io.client for iOS: How to extend socket timeout?
I am attempting to use socket.io to connect to an NTRIP server. I can see the auth request go out and an ICY 200 OK response come back but the connection times out after 60 seconds and is stuck in a reconnect loop after that.
Code:
let extraHeaders = [
    "Accept-Encoding" : "*",
    "Accept-Language" : "*",
    "User-Agent" : "NTRIP KNTRIPClient/20240328",
    "Accept" : "*/*",
    "Connection" : "close",
    "Authorization" : "Basic a3Vib3RheTE6a3Vib3RheTE="
]

manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://184.105.97.107:9002")!)
manager?.setConfigs(
    SocketIOClientConfiguration(
        arrayLiteral: .log(true),
        /*.reconnects(false),*/
        .path("/AZGPS_RTCM3"),
        .extraHeaders(extraHeaders)
    )
)


socket = manager?.defaultSocket

socket?.onAny { socketAnyEvent in
    print(socketAnyEvent)
}

socket?.connect()

Log:
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: statusChange with data: [connecting, 2]
SocketAnyEvent: Event: statusChange items: Optional([connecting, 2])
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Joining namespace /
LOG SocketManager: Tried connecting socket when engine isn't open. Connecting
LOG SocketManager: Adding engine
LOG SocketEngine: Starting engine. Server: http://184.105.97.107:9002
LOG SocketEngine: Handshaking
LOG SocketEnginePolling: Doing polling GET http://184.105.97.107:9002/AZGPS_RTCM3/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4
Task <5CE2FA1D-F6A4-4EA2-9412-FAB544203387>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c08840 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <5CE2FA1D-F6A4-4EA2-9412-FAB544203387>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <5CE2FA1D-F6A4-4EA2-9412-FAB544203387>.<1>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://184.105.97.107:9002/AZGPS_RTCM3/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://184.105.97.107:9002/AZGPS_RTCM3/?transport=polling&b64=1&EIO=4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}
ERROR SocketEnginePolling: The request timed out.
ERROR SocketEngine: The request timed out.
ERROR SocketManager: The request timed out.
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: error with data: ["The request timed out."]
SocketAnyEvent: Event: error items: Optional(["The request timed out."])
LOG SocketManager: Starting reconnect
LOG SocketManager: Trying to reconnect
LOG SocketIOClient{/}: Handling event: reconnectAttempt with data: [-1]
SocketAnyEvent: Event: reconnectAttempt items: Optional([-1])

Wire Shark:


FYI, the timeoutAfter parameter isn't actually used for network requests, it's just to check if the connection (handshake) succeeded (from what I can tell looking at the source code). If you need a timeout longer than the system default (60s),  you probably need to change the URLSessionConfiguration, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/23428960/95309

Ref: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift/blob/master/Source/SocketIO/Client/SocketIOClient.swift#L151

@ClausJørgensen I was noticing that the timeoutAfter wasn't actually doing anything, hence my confusion, let me try your suggestion and see what happens.

@ClausJørgensen looking at the source code for SocketEngine it looks like I have no control what so ever over the timeout var reqPolling = URLRequest(url: urlPolling, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 60.0)
